# Can someone please help resolve sql error?

Tags: mysql

I tried following code on dbeaver

```
select employees.emp_no, employees.first_name, 
departments.dept_no, departments.dept_name

from employees,
 departments,
 dept_emp

where employees.emp_no = dept_emp.emp_no

and dept_emp.dept_no = departments.dept_no
```

And i am getting following error
[image]

Comment: The error says "line 1" and refers to your `where` clause, which is not line 1 of your query.  Your SQL looks like it has spaces, if your cursor is on the `where` clause the query starts there.  So dbeaver is running just the `where` clause.  Try removing spaces or querying with your cursor on the first line (select) and adding a `;` to the end

Comment: Try to use ` ` around table names, I think the _ underscore could be a problem.

Comment: There is no syntax error if you run all the code https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8b20482a781e4b9472ebb9254216e4ec but you should ditch the comma joins in favour of explicit joins.

Comment: thankyou very much ,script worked by removing the spaces